# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.externals.six'

Tags: python, machine-learning, sklearn

Não consigo executar o script, porque ele está acusando que não existe o módulo **'sklearn.externals.si**x'. Já procurei soluções, refiz o venv e não da certo. Esse módulo se tornou obsoleto ou algo do tipo?
Por favor me ajudem.

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import pandas as pd
import mglearn

iris_dataset = load_iris()

#print(f'Keys: {iris_dataset}')

'''
train_test_slit() extrai 75% dos dados de iris_dataset['data'] e iris_dataset['target'] para treinar e os outros 25% para teste

'''

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_text = train_test_split(
    iris_dataset['data'], iris_dataset['target'],    random_state=0)

iris_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(X_train, columns=iris_dataset.feature_names)

grr = pd.plotting.scatter_matrix(iris_dataframe, c=y_train, figsize=(
    15, 15), marker='o', hist_kwds={'bins': 20}, s=60, alpha=.8, cmap=mglearn.cm3)
```

A saída:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Paulo\Documents\Cursos\MachineLearningPython\Cap 1\firstMLAlghoritm.py", line 4, in <module>
    import mglearn
  File "c:\Users\Paulo\Documents\Cursos\MachineLearningPython\venv\lib\site-packages\mglearn\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from . import plots
  File "c:\Users\Paulo\Documents\Cursos\MachineLearningPython\venv\lib\site-packages\mglearn\plots.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .plot_interactive_tree import plot_tree_progressive, plot_tree_partition
  File "c:\Users\Paulo\Documents\Cursos\MachineLearningPython\venv\lib\site-packages\mglearn\plot_interactive_tree.py", line 6, in <module>
    from sklearn.externals.six import StringIO  # doctest: +SKIP
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.externals.six'
```

Answer (score 1):

O sklearn.externals.six foi extinto com a versão scikit-learn 0.21 . Faça o Downgrade sua versão do scikit-learn. Veja o código a seguir:

No jupyter notebook:!pip install --upgrade scikit-learn==0.20.3

No terminal:pip install --upgrade scikit-learn==0.20.3

Após isso o módulo  sklearn.externals.six será reconhecido

Answer (score 0):

Pela mensagem de erro o módulo `mglearn` usa esse [script](https://github.com/amueller/introduction_to_ml_with_python/blob/master/mglearn/plot_interactive_tree.py), que precisa do `sklearn.externals.six`, sendo que o `sklearn.externals.six` foi retirado do sklearn na versão [0.21.0](https://scikit-learn.org/dev/whats_new/v0.21.html#version-0-21-0). Para utlizar o `mglearn` você necessita fazer o downgrade do sklearn para uma versão anterior a 0.21.0.

Comment: Tentei fazer o downgrade, mas diz que não encontra uma versão que satisfaça. Usei: pip install sklearn==0.20.4. E a saída: ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement sklearn==0.20.4 (from versions: 0.0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for sklearn==0.20.4. Olhei as versões no site, mas não consegui fazer o downgrade

Answer (score -1):

Nesse caso, imagino que não vá fazer tanta diferença você utilizar essa biblioteca. Se quiser rodar o código sem ela, faça o seguinte:

1) Remova:

```
import mglearn
```

2) Remova o último parâmetro da última linha:

```
, cmap=mglearn.cm3
```